# stripe payment error: uncaught exception

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe payment gateway in my application.
Everything works well for the static payment i.e. $55 or $5 or any other amount. But I want to create application which charges dynamically based on hours and hourly rate. when I wrote my logic and tried it, shows me an error like.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'Invalid integer: $price' in C:\wamp64\www\PROJECT\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php:120 from API request 'req_jN42fBMzXZqjVB' in C:\wamp64\www\PROJECT\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php on line 120

( ! ) Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest: Invalid integer: $price in C:\wamp64\www\PROJECT\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php on line 120
```

below is my code for the file:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
require_once ('dbconfigpdo.php');
print_r($_SESSION);

$parkingslot= $_SESSION["parkingslot"];
$booking_start = $_SESSION["booking_start"];
$booking_end = $_SESSION["booking_end"];
$booking_start_time = $_SESSION["booking_start_time"];
$booking_end_time = $_SESSION["booking_end_time"];
//$price = $_SESSION['price'];
$a = new DateTime($booking_start_time);
$b = new DateTime($booking_end_time);
$interval = $a->diff($b);

echo $duration=$interval->format("%H");
var_dump($duration);
$price = 3 * $duration;

echo $duration;
echo $price;
//echo "$booking_end";
//check whether stripe token is not empty
if(!empty($_POST['stripeToken'])){
    //get token, card and user info from the form
    $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $card_num = $_POST['card_num'];
    $card_cvc = $_POST['cvc'];
    $card_exp_month = $_POST['exp_month'];
    $card_exp_year = $_POST['exp_year'];

    //include Stripe PHP library
    require_once('stripe-php\init.php');

    //set api key
    $stripe = array(
      "secret_key"      => "sk_test_yzsJAYlaZBO5SUcoga067K1s",
      "publishable_key" => "pk_test_ApEdDkstpR0xRuASqSbz0fn9"
    );

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

    //add customer to stripe
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        'email' => $email,
        'source'  => $token
    ));

    //item information
    $itemName = $parkingslot;
    $itemNumber = $parkingslot;
    $itemPrice = $price;
    $currency = "CAD";
    $orderID = rand();

    //charge a credit or a debit card
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        'customer' => $customer->id,
        'amount'   => $itemPrice,
        'currency' => $currency,
        'description' => $itemName,
        'metadata' => array(
            'order_id' => $orderID
        )
    ));

    //retrieve charge details
    $chargeJson = $charge->jsonSerialize();

    //check whether the charge is successful
    if($chargeJson['amount_refunded'] == 0 && empty($chargeJson['failure_code']) && $chargeJson['paid'] == 1 && $chargeJson['captured'] == 1){
        //order details 
        $amount = $chargeJson['amount'];
        $balance_transaction = $chargeJson['balance_transaction'];
        $currency = $chargeJson['currency'];
        $status = $chargeJson['status'];
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        //include database config file
        include_once 'dbConfig1.php';

        //insert tansaction data into the database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders(name,email,card_num,card_cvc,card_exp_month,card_exp_year,item_name,item_number,item_price,item_price_currency,paid_amount,paid_amount_currency,txn_id,payment_status,created,modified) VALUES('".$name."','".$email."','".$card_num."','".$card_cvc."','".$card_exp_month."','".$card_exp_year."','".$itemName."','".$itemNumber."','".$itemPrice."','".$currency."','".$amount."','".$currency."','".$balance_transaction."','".$status."','".$date."','".$date."')";
        $insert = $db->query($sql);
        $last_insert_id = $db->insert_id;

        //if order inserted successfully
        if($last_insert_id && $status == 'succeeded'){
           $sql="UPDATE `fleming_dwing` SET `Status` = 'RESERVED' WHERE `ParkingSlotNo`=$parkingslot";

    $st=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute();
            $statusMsg = "<h2>The transaction was successful.</h2><h4>Order ID: {$last_insert_id}</h4>";
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Transaction has been failed";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = "Transaction has been failed";
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = "Form submission error.......";
}

//show success or error message
echo $statusMsg;
```

?>
I think I made some mistake while assigning values to stripe payment variable.
please help me out.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you throw an exception, but nothing anywhere in your code catches it after it's thrown. `$price = 3 * $duration;` if `$duration` is null/empty/not set then this might cause an issue. Try dumping out the value of `$duration`

Comment: Also, are the vars where you set this all correct: `$itemPrice = '$price';`? Did you mean to put apostrophes?

Comment: @James I did put those apostrophes.

Comment: Variables in single quotes are not expanded. Meaning when you `echo $itemPrice` it will output `$price` (that string, not the value stored in the variable)

Comment: '$price' is the stting '$price' not the value ofthe variable

Comment: @James I already removed those apostrophes but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: And what was the outcome of `var_dump($duration);`? You do this: `echo $duration=$interval->format("%H");
$price = 3 * $duration;` and the error is about `$price` and as `$validation` is likely null (cos you echo it not set it) then the value in `$price` is not right

Comment: @james I just tried your suggestion it gave me following reply.  

C:\wamp64\www\PROJECT\paymentsubmit.php:20:string '03' (length=2)

Comment: @James does it have something to do with string? I mean kind of data type?

Comment: Without seeing all your code it's hard to say. Where the exception is thrown (as per the error details) instead of throwing the exception try dumping out the value it complains about

Comment: @James I have updated the code check it. thank you

Comment: @james I solved that Issue. the problem was duration and price were in string I converted them into integer. but then I encountered another problem which is stripe only takes amount in cents. so I multiply it by 100 but when I see my database it shows me $600 as amount charged.

Comment: Look at the Stripe docs (I've never really used it) what is the required type for that data? ie is it int? Or could it be float?